# WhatsApp reply via notification not working

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I am currently on Android 9 Pie. Whenever I get a WhatsApp message and I try to reply to it from notification, it freezes. More frustratingly, it doesn't happen every time but say, 1 out of 3 times it happens.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Receive a WhatsApp message
2. Click Reply on the notification
3. Type message in the notification
4. Click Arrow (send) button.

Result:
The arrow turns to a circular progress bar and the notification stays like that. The message is not sent.

I have tried clean installing WhatsApp, it still persists. Not sure if anyone else is facing this. No other apps like Telegram or even the SMS app are having any such problem.

Any solution will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the way WhatsApp is handling PendingIntents.  I think you would be better off reaching out to the WhatsApp support channels as this doesn't seem like it is a problem with Android itself.